# Accessing Office365's Active Directory

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, office-365, azure, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement a Single-Sign-On functionality for an Intranet web-application that will sit on SharePoint.

Now, I have done a lot of research on this and informed myself about the authentication flow for Office 365. I have also discovered that there is an `Active Directory` operating under the hood, managing the user-database among other things.

To get the SSO working I will need to create an access control namespace for our enterprise directory.

**I could however not find out how to access the settings for the Active Directory of our Office365 enterprise account:**

- I tried logging into the Azure Management Portal with my enterprise credentials. It said I had no Azure account.
- Our Office365 administrator tried the same thing. No success here either.

Is there any way to activate the management portal for our Office365 account? Or am I misunderstanding something?